# Як не гроші, то полова. В тебе жінка чорноброва. У чому суть?

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми

Який зміст у Щедрику Леонтовича мають ці рядки:

> В тебе товар весь хороший,
>
> Будеш мати мірку грошей,
>
> Як не гроші, то полова,
>
> В тебе жінка чорноброва.

У якому значенні використовується тут слово "полова"

- як рештки обмолоченого зерна (і тоді значення речення буде таке: Навіть, як нічого не заробиш, то й так маєш гарну жінку)
- чи як спільнокоріневе від слова "половина"(і тоді значення речення буде таке: Навіть, як не багато грошей заробиш, то половину.)

Або про що мова?

Answer (score 5):

> [Полова](http://sum.in.ua/s/polova)
>
> 2. *перен*. Що-небудь невагоме, несерйозне, таке, що не має цінності, суттєвого значення.
>
> <sup>Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 7, 1976. — Стор. 87.</sup>

Тобто, гадаю, **дрібʼязок**. Ось літературні приклади¹, де *полова* і *грошва*:

> *Пху! От що мені гроші! Мені гроші — полова! — кричав палкий бурлака* ([«Микола Джеря»](http://ukrlit.org/nechui_levytskyi_ivan_semenovych/mykola_dzheria/31), Нечуй‑Левицький) *Так ви забрали собі в голову, що гроші в мене як полова — лопатою гребу* ([Михайло Стельмах](http://sum.in.ua/s/lopata), II, 1962, 373); *Багатому вітер гроші несе, а бідному половою очі засипає* ([приказка](http://igra1.com/ua/pryslivya-ta-prykazky/b/bahatomu-viter-hroshi-nese-a-bidnomu-polovoyu-ochi-zasypaye.htm)); *сипати гроші як полову* ([сталий вираз](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile.php?transfer=folders/de/djnmgi.html)) ітд.

---

¹ Дякую [Artemix](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/69)-ові.